# Why does bindValue set fields to the last value?

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, bindparam, bindvalue

I am trying to run an UPDATE from a $_POST array using a foreach statement with bindValue. But the fields in the table are always set to the last values.  I thought that this problem would arise only if I used bindParam?  I call the bind function as follows:

```
public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                    default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }
```

And then update the table with the following foreach statement

```
        $database->query('UPDATE documents SET
    document=:document,
    dateissued=:dateissued,
    expirydate=:expirydate
    WHERE peopleid=:peopleid');

foreach ($_POST['document'] as $i => $item) {
        $trim_value = trim($item);
                if (!empty($trim_value)){
                                        $database->bind(':document',$_POST['document'][$i]);
                                        $database->bind(':dateissued',$_POST['dateissued'][$i]);
                                        $database->bind(':expirydate',$_POST['expirydate'][$i]);
                                        $database->bind(':peopleid',$_POST['peopleid'][$i]);
                }
                $database->execute();

    }
```

Any idea why this would be happening?  I use the same function with INSERT and it works fine.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Rewrite your code to vanilla PDO and everything would work.

Comment: It works for insert but not for update, this is what is confusing me.  The only difference I can think of is that with update the html form already has a value which is then modified.  But bindValue should work...

Comment: Thanks, I tried vanilla PDO but it still saves only the last values.  It probably has something to do with the fact that I am already using a foreach statement to loop through the fields in the table to build the form.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Did you do output your input array for the debugging purpose?

Comment: Yes, debugDumpParams() shows the array being updated in each loop correctly, but only the last loop is updated for all records. Confirmed by Var_dump as well.

Comment: print_r displays Array ([0] => doc1, [1] => doc2,  [2] => doc3) but var_dump shows only string(4) "doc3".  So the foreach statement in the UPDATE works correctly but it for some reason only the last value is update in the table.

Comment: Solved it! Really silly mistake, but all I had to do is to pass an additional field to the where clause to identify the row as well.